# Prove that the image $\alpha$ of $X$ in $\left(\mathbb{F}_3[X]/(X^3-X^2+1)\right)^{\times}$ is a generator

Tags: finite-fields

I'm trying to do an exercise of my homework that sais I have to prove that the iamge of $X$ in $K^{\times}=\left(\mathbb{F}_3[X]/(X^3-X^2+1)\right)^{\times}$ is a generator.

Acording to what I know, $K^{\times}$ have 26 elements. So, $\alpha^{26}$ must be 1 and $\alpha^{13}$ must be $-1$. But I've calculate this several times and I have $\alpha^{13}=X^2-1$

is the exercise wrong or it's me?

Comment: I'm afraid it's you :-( $\alpha^4 = \alpha^2 + 2\alpha +2$; $\alpha^8 = \alpha^2 + \alpha + 2$; $\alpha^{12} = \alpha^2 + 2\alpha$; $\alpha^{13} = -1$.

Comment: @Magdiragdad You are the hero of the day

Comment: Glad to be of service :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $x^3-x^2+1$ is given to be an irreducible cubic polynomial in $\mathbb F_3[x]$,
and it must be a divisor of $$x^{26}-1 = (x^{13}-1)(x^{13}+1)$$ So $x^3-x^2+1$ must be a divisor of $x^{13}-1$ or of $x^{13}+1$.  If the former,
then $\alpha$, a root of $x^3-x^2+1$ , has order 13 and cannot be a generator
of $K^\times$. So, you must check whether $x^3-x^2+1$  divides $x^{13}-1$ or not, and
you are done.

Comment: Thank you or your answer. Can i make you a  question? Why $x^3-x^2+1$ must be a divisor of $x^{26}-1$?

Comment: @MaríaCC If $f(x) \in \mathbb F_p[x]$ is irreducible, then $\mathbb F_p[x]/f(x)$ is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb F_{p^{\deg {f}}}$ whose multiplicative group is cyclic of order $p^{\deg {f}} - 1$.